# How can I update all the value in the column base on the order of another column in the same table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update, sequence

Says I have a table like this in Oracle DB.

```
S_Name    S_NO   S_SID
Michael   (NULL)  C40
Jay       (NULL)  A44
David     (NULL)  G71
Chris     (NULL)  Y53
...       ...     ...
```

I would like to update all S_NO base on the ordered S_SID.
Ihat mean (A44 > C40 > G71 > Y53)

```
S_Name    S_NO   S_SID
Michael   2       C40
Jay       1       A44
David     3       G71
Chris     4       Y53
...       ...     ...
```

Comment: `UPDATE FROM` using a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER  BY S_SID)`

Comment: Are you sure this is not something better calculated on the fly as needed?  Would you not need to update this after any insert/updates?

Comment: Is S_SID always unique across all rows in the table?

Comment: It is for something 'initial ' setting. After that, not update is needed but will need insert using 'max(S_NO) +1'

Comment: S_SID is unique in the table

Answer (score 2):

You can get the order using ROW_NUMBER() so the following select

```
 SELECT S_name, S_SID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S_SID DESC) as RN
```

Give you the value just put that in an update.

---

**UPDATE**

This code

```
UPDATE TABLE SET S_NO = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S_NO) AS RN FROM TABLE)
```

Does not join back to the the table so the server assumes you only want to get one value from the sub-query and assign that to all rows.

You need to join on an index:

```
UPDATE TABLE AS MAIN_TABLE
  SET MAIN_TABLE.S_NO = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S_NO) AS RN 
              FROM TABLE AS SUB_TABLE
              WHERE MAIN_TABLE.INDEX_COLUMN = SUB_TABLE.INDEX_COLUMN
              )
```

Comment: Why DESC? The sample provided seemed to be ascending.

Comment: UPDATE TABLE SET S_NO = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S_NO) AS RN FROM TABLE)

Comment: but it returns "single-row subquery returns more than one row" How can I update all of them in a single query ? Thanks!